# Modify Key of the object by appending a field from Value into Key using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to apply [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) on the following problem:-

```
{
   "alpha": {
      "reg": "alpha1",
      "reg2": "alpha2"
   },
   "beta": {
      "reg": "beta1",
      "reg2": "beta2"  
   }
}
```

Output

```
{
   "v:alpha|reg:alpha1": {
      "reg": "alpha1",
      "reg2": "alpha2"
   },
   "v:beta|reg:beta1": {
      "reg": "beta1",
      "reg2": "beta2"  
   }
}
```

Basically, the output will be the object modifying the key by combining the key and a field from the value into the key and forming the new key.

For e.g. if the key="alpha", value is an object with key reg="alpha1". so the key should be modified to `v:alpha|reg:alpha1`. v being unique string appending at the start of every key, and then appending `reg:alpha1` to the key.

Thanks

Comment: `"v:beta|reg:alpha2"` --- what is the logic of adding the part that comes after the `|` character?

Comment: @zerkms Each value has field "reg" with a value. I need to append that into the key with field name as well. Basically, the object remains same as is, with key being transformed.

Comment: Why is it `v:beta|reg:alpha2` and not `v:beta|reg:beta1` then?

Comment: @zerkms that are the requirements.

Comment: And now we're again in the beginning: what are the requirements?

Comment: `const result = Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [\`v:${k}|reg:${v.reg}\`]: v}), {});` - no ramda required

Comment: @zerkms i was thinking of using rambda using composition..

Comment: What is the point of using ramda for something that can be done with just JS? I composed built-in JS functions.

Comment: @zerkms I understand, but it just makes the code more declarative, point-free and less use of variables etc. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: "more declarative" --- more declarative than a single-statement solution that I provided? Only 0 statements is less than 1. "less use of variables etc" --- how can you tell that if you don't have a ramda-based solution? "point-free" -- and you want that because it is "cool" or there is some technical reason to prefer it?

Comment: @zerkms no such technical reason.  But it makes coding easier and hassle free. For complex problem and transformations, it becomes unmanageable.

Comment: "point-free" "makes coding easier and hassle free" "For complex problem and transformations, it becomes unmanageable". I see. It makes it so easy for this trivial problem so that you cannot even implement it... But anyway, let's see the "better" solution than what I provided.

Comment: @rgeek I recommend you get in touch with fp fundamentals before worrying about things you don't yet understand. You'll never be able to appreciate them if you don't know the trade-offs you're making

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what people are saying in the comments is mostly right.  (Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of Ramda.)

Let's imagine Ramda has a `renameBy` function:

```
const renameBy = curry((fn, obj) => pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(pair => [apply(fn, pair), pair[1]]),
  fromPairs
)(obj))
```

Ramda doesn't include this now, but there is a [slightly less powerful version](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#rename-keys-of-an-object) in Ramda's [Cookbook](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook).  It's certainly conceivable that it will one day be included.  But failing that, you could include such a function in your own codebase.  (If we really tried, we could probably make that points-free, but as I'm trying to explain, that is probably unnecessary.)

How much does this gain you?

You could then write a transformation function like

```
const transform = renameBy((k, v) => `v:${k}|reg:${v.reg}`);
```

Granted, that is now simpler than the one in [zerkms's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567389/#comment74186841_43567389)

But the fundamentally complex bit of that version is retained here: the function that performs string interpolation on your key and value to yield a new key.  Any attempt to make that points-free is likely to be substantially uglier than this version.

Perhaps this is worth it to you.  It does separate concerns between the action of renaming keys and your particular key-generation scheme.  And it reduces visual complexity... but only if you move that `renameBy` out of sight into some utilities library.  If you're going to have multiple uses of `renameBy`, or if you simply prefer building up a more complete utility library in order to keep your other code more focused, then this might be a reasonable approach.

But it doesn't reduce the essential complexity of the code.

I do look to points-free solutions when it's reasonable.  But they are just another tool in my toolbox.  They are only worth it if they make the code more readable and maintainable.  If they add complexity, I would suggest you don't bother.

You can see this version in the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%22alpha%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22reg%22%3A%20%22alpha1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22reg2%22%3A%20%22alpha2%22%0A%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%22beta%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22reg%22%3A%20%22beta1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22reg2%22%3A%20%22beta2%22%20%20%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20renameBy%20%3D%20curry%28%28fn%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20pipe%28%0A%20%20toPairs%2C%0A%20%20map%28pair%20%3D%3E%20%5Bapply%28fn%2C%20pair%29%2C%20pair%5B1%5D%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20fromPairs%0A%29%28obj%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20transform%20%3D%20renameBy%28%28k%2C%20v%29%20%3D%3E%20%60v%3A%24%7Bk%7D%7Creg%3A%24%7Bv.reg%7D%60%29%3B%0A%0Atransform%28data%29)**.